# How should I link to LLVM libraries?

Tags: llvm, clang

When I use command "`gcc .. ../../*.so`", there are the following error messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/demonwnb/build/src/*.so: error: undefined reference to 'llvm::raw_ostream::operator<<(void const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/demonwnb/build/src/*.so: error: undefined reference to 'clang::DeclarationName::printName(llvm::raw_ostream&) const'
```

I think that I do not link "llvm library" correctly, so how should I do?

Answer (score 6):

You need to tell your compiler where to load the libraries from, which can be done using the llvm-config command.

You could set the following symbols in your makefile

```
CC = g++

LLVM_MODULES = core jit native

CPPFLAGS = `llvm-config --cppflags $(LLVM_MODULES)`
LDFLAGS = `llvm-config --ldflags $(LLVM_MODULES)`
LIBS = `llvm-config --libs $(LLVM_MODULES)`

all:
    $(CC) *.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o MyOutput
main:
    find -name '*.cpp' -print0 | xargs -0 $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS)
```

Comment: @kunou: This is an extract from my makefile of a project that uses LLVM. You might have to tweak a bit to make it work for your project!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that LLVM builds itself as set of static libraries. Some linkers a sensitive to order of -lLLVM* flags, so it's **highly** recommended to use llvm-config script. Or `llvm_map_components_to_libraries()` if you are using CMake.

Comment: @kunou You could mark this as the right answer if it worked for you!

Comment: What is the `find` for?

Comment: @Galaxy: The find is to find all the files that have a .cpp extension. This list will be input to gcc for compilation. It's not absolutely necessary. You could even do a $(CC) file1.cpp file2.cpp -c $(CPPFLAGS) if you want to statically list the files in the Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using g++ to do the link? Those are C++ libraries and gcc doesn't pass the C++ libraries to the linker.